# Devise Routes in a rails plugin are incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am developing a rails plugin. I want to use devise in the plugin for authentication.

It seems that the routes are drawn incorrectly:

```
Routes for Subscribem::Engine:
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       subscribem/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       subscribem/sessions#create
```

They should be:

```
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format) devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format) devise/sessions#create
```

This is the route file of the plugin:

```
Subscribem::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, class_name: "Subscribem::User"
```

The plugin is isolated with a namespace:

```
module Subscribem
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Subscribem
```

If I remove the isolate_namespace the devise routes will ok. But I would still like to isolate the plugins own controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an option:

in the plugins routes I can override the controllers:

```
devise_for :users, class_name: "Subscribem::User", controllers: { sessions: 'devise/sessions', passwords: 'devise/passwords', registrations: 'devise/registrations' }
```

But more options are welcome